# PHP does not find Firebird PDO extensions' dll on File-System

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I have a PHP app that does not connect to FB.
The \ext folder (installed by PHP 8.2.8 installer) has the correct DLL that PHP provides.

The file is marked as:

Name: php_pdo_firebird.dll
Version: 8.2.8.0
Copyright: The PHP Group
Original filename: php_pdo_firebird.dll

In PHP.ini the extension (that comes commented out by the installer) is no more commented, i.e. the semicolon is removed.

What am I missing?

Failure:

When I start PHO server with: php -S localhost:8000 -t [folderName]

System answers:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'php_pdo_firebird' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird (The specified
> module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_php_pdo_firebird.dll (The
> specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'php_pdo_firebird' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird (The specified
> module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_php_pdo_firebird.dll (The
> specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide reference to the PHP 8.8 installer, what is that and where did you obtain it (link is fine)? And it is very important that you read the error message again and check the pathnames where PHP tried to load the file. They are different to what you tell you have configured. Likely a configuration error. Verify that.

Comment: The error says it tried `C:\php\ext\php_pdo_firebird` and `C:\php\ext\php_php_pdo_firebird.dll`, but the file is called `php_pdo_firebird.dll`. What exactly do you have in that `php.ini`? I'm guessing you have `php_pdo_firebird`, instead of `pdo_firebird` or something like that.